# How can I understand that power is absorbed or delivered from circuit?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, circuit-analysis, resistors

In the below example, we found that power is minus. I don't understand the reason isn't it current (+)? So how can power be (-)?

[image]

Comment: From what you have shown, power supplied by the voltage source is positive.

Comment: It is unclear why whe calculation has a negative sign so it can't be answered. Maybe it's explained in the text?

Comment: @Andyaka Question just says 'Find the current and power supplied by the 40 V source in the circuit.'

Comment: @Justme Question just says 'Find the current and power supplied by the 40 V source in the circuit.'

Comment: The power supplied is positive. End of story; either the book is wrong or you are not revealing important information.

Comment: If the book has chosen a generic notation that power into something like a load is positive, then by that logic, power out of something has to be negative. But it's you who has the book. The book may have an error or it's just too pedantic.

Comment: @XcellentEEE you are not thinking clearly ... how does reversing a resistor make any difference? ... changing the current direction through a resistor does not change the resistor into a current source